# useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo in SCORM 2004

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I am dealing with a set of courses that were developed by a prior developer who is no longer with the company.  I'm trying to debug these courses in our new LMS.  The courses set the controlMode attributes "useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo" and "useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo" to false for virtually all items.

e.g.:

```
            <item identifier="sco_43337avg" identifierref="res-43337avg" isvisible="true">
                <title>Introduction</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:controlMode choice="true" choiceExit="true" flow="true" forwardOnly="false" useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo="false" useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo="false" />

                    <imsss:sequencingRules>
                     ...
```

In SCORM 2004, 3rd Edition, the Content Aggregation Model document states this about useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo:

> useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo (optional, default value = true) – Indicates that the attempt progress information for the children of the activity will only be used (or not used if value = false) in rule evaluations and rollup if that information was recorded during the current attempt on the activity.

This seems to say that, if "false", progress info from the current attempt will NOT be used in rule evaluations and rollup ... does this mean that objective info from a prior attempt will be used, instead? Or does this mean that NO progress info from the children of the activity will be used?  Prior attempt info is not retained by the LMS, is it?  So why would this attribute ever be set to "false"?

What would be a scenario where you would wish to set this to "false"?

Should I simply set these all to "true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If **useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo** and **useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo**
   are set to false, the LMS will use tracking information of the
   previous attempt (if any) unless the current attempt has recorded
   its tracking info.
2. If **useCurrentAttemptObjectiveInfo** and **useCurrentAttemptProgressInfo**
   are set to true, the LMS will  use the tracking info of the current
   attempt only ignoring any tracking info recorded for the previous
   attempts.

Let's say a learner has completed an activity and tracking info for that activity has been recorded,
then the learner went back to the same activity later but no tracking info has been recorded. If these controlMode elements are set to false, the LMS will use the tracking info of the previous attempt since there is no tracking info for the current activity. If they are set to true, the LMS will base its rollup on the tracking info of the current attempt only.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I had thought that the LMS was only required to keep data for the learner attempt if the learner attempt was suspended. So the LMS should keep tracking data from the prior user attempt?

Comment: Oh, and can I ask where you quoted the text from for your points 1 and 2?  Is that from an ADL document?